# Delete button on PHP echo table not working

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

Below is my code for a PHP echo delete that contains a delete button. When pressed I want that entry to be deleted from the database

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * ,CONCAT (HomeScore,'-',AwayScore) AS Score, CONCAT(Against) AS Game FROM Fixture WHERE TeamID='9' ORDER BY Date DESC");
echo "<table id='customers' border='1'>;

<tr>
<th>FixtureID</th>
<th>Competition</th>
<th>Match</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Score</th>
<th>test</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['FixtureID'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Competition'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row["Against"] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Date'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Time'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Score'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><form method=post>
                    <input name=id type=hidden value='".$row['FixtureID']."';>
                    <input type=submit name=submit value=Delete>
                    </form></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
echo "</tr>";  
}
}
echo "</table>";

// delete record
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
if(isset($_POST['FixtureID']))
{
$id = FixtureID;
$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM Fixture WHERE FixtureID =$id");
if(!$sql)
{
    echo ("Could not delete rows" .mysql_error());
}
}
}
```

How do I get this to work? Also FixtureID is stored as an integer in the database.

Comment: i think your not mention the result

Comment: Your looking at the variable `$_POST['FixtureID']`, shouldn't it be `$_POST['id']`? Might be worth that putting the `//delete record` block before the display code, that way you don't need to refresh the page once you have clicked the delete button.

Comment: Use action in the form where you want to post your data and rather creating form in each row you can use anchor link. pass id in query string or using ajax.

Comment: You are also creating form in a loop which means you are creating a button with a same name "id". this results in to array of the elements of same name.

Comment: `$id=$_POST['FixtureID'];`

Comment: Also, Google `PHP SQL Injection`

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution — Don't use a link. Links make GET requests. Deleting things should be done with a POST request (or a DELETE request in a RESTful API).

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution — For the purposes of submitting a form, only form controls in that form count. So only the input that is in the current form matters. There is no array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with these changes :

```
// delete record
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id'])) {
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM Fixture WHERE FixtureID =$id");
  if(!$sql) {
    echo ("Could not delete rows" .mysql_error());
  }
}
```

Edit :

```
// Delete record if ID submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id'])) {
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM Fixture WHERE FixtureID =$id");
  if(!$sql) {
    echo ("Could not delete rows" .mysql_error());
  }
}

// Get datas from BDD
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * ,CONCAT (HomeScore,'-',AwayScore) AS Score, CONCAT(Against) AS Game FROM Fixture WHERE TeamID='9' ORDER BY Date DESC");

// Display data
echo "
<table id='customers' border='1'>
<tr>
<th>FixtureID</th>
<th>Competition</th>
<th>Match</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Score</th>
<th>test</th>
</tr>";

// For each result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['FixtureID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Competition'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["Against"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Time'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Score'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><form method=post>
                    <input name=id type=hidden value='".$row['FixtureID']."';>
                    <input type=submit name=submit value=Delete>
                    </form></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: @Aliasse Thank you cant accept the answer yet as not enough time has gone by but i will. How do i get it to refresh after the click so it disappears automatically?

Comment: @user3535330 — Move the code that deletes the row so it runs before the code that lists all the rows.

Comment: @Quentin is right. Move this code before your data table and before your data query.

Comment: @Aliassse and  I've updated my code to show everything sorry where exactly does it go im having no luck

Comment: @Quentin I've updated my code to show everything sorry where exactly does it go im having no luck

Comment: @user3535330 Put your delete code before your query. This way, you'll delete before you get datas.

Answer (score 0):

`$id` value  is not properly set

```
$id = $_POST['FixtureID'];
```

Answer (score 0):

just try this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$id = $_POST['id']; //  here you should use form post value
$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM Fixture WHERE FixtureID =$id");
if(!$sql)
{
    echo ("Could not delete rows" .mysql_error());
}
}
}
```